# What rule do I need to allow access to users data in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, angularfire

I'm learning Firestore and have built an angular app. I'm using Firebase authentication and having trouble figuring out the rules to use to allow a user access to their data. So for example a products collection which each product has a userId which is actually their email address.

Example:
[image]

The current rule I have is as follows and is not working (i've tried everything I can figure based on docs, stackoverflow, etc.):

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userEmail} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /products/{userId}{
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid.userEmail == userId
    }  
  }
}
```

The only thing i've done that does work (i.e. I get all products back) is if I do a match/{document=**) which opens it up to anyone which is NOT what I want. :)

Any ideas?

Edit: Incase someone is wondering about the angular code. Again, if I set the rule to allow anything I DO get data back. If I restrict it, so far I get nothing. So, I know the code works (getAll) thus it must be the rules are not right.

Edit: I updated the code to write the users email to the console just before requesting all products data from the store. It successfully output the user's email.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { Product } from '../models/product.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductsService {

  private dbPath = '/products';

  productsRef: AngularFirestoreCollection<Product>;

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.productsRef = db.collection(this.dbPath);
  }

  getAll(): AngularFirestoreCollection<Product>{
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      console.log('Dashboard: user', user);

      if (user) {
          let emailLower = user.email.toLowerCase();
          console.log("Email: " + emailLower);
      }
  });

    return this.productsRef;
  }

  create(product: Product): any {
    return this.productsRef.add(product);
  }

  update(id: string, data: any): Promise<void>{
    return this.productsRef.doc(id).update(data);
  }

  delete(id: string): Promise<void> {
    return this.productsRef.doc(id).delete();
  }
}
```

Comment: Security rules do nothing on their own. Please edit your question to include the code that doesn't do what you expect it to do against these rules.

Comment: you can checkout these documentation for editing security rules.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen At first I didn't understand since those rules are the code but rereading your comment, I posted the angular code making the calls to firebase.

Comment: My guess is that you're accessing the database when the user is not signed in yet. Try logging the UID of the user in your code right before you access the database.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Ok, I added logging of the signed in user's email and it worked fine. Printed it as expected just before requesting all data.

Comment: `this.afAuth.authState.subscribe()` fires once the user is signed in, so adding that doesn't change anything about the flow yet. Try logging `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` or `getAuth().currentUser.uid`, as those execute synchronously, and thus are certain to give you the value just before you connect to the database.

Comment: @slashbrackets Posted an answer, Is it helpful?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [allow read, write: if request.auth != null;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69648609/allow-read-write-if-request-auth-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is some  issue with the security rules built. You can refer to the  [Firestore security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) to learn more about writing rules and for testing your rules you can refer [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started#testing_rules) where mentioned :

> Cloud Firestore provides a rules simulator that you can use to test
> your ruleset. You can access the simulator from the [Rules tab](https://firebase.corp.google.com/u/0/project/_/firestore/rules) in the
> Cloud Firestore section of the Firebase console.
> The rules simulator lets you simulate authenticated and
> unauthenticated reads, writes, and deletes.

**a)** From the screenshot of the Firestore database products collection, the document ID appears to be an auto-generated alphanumeric sequence. So below match rules are going to match document ID (auto-generated) in {userEmail} & {userId} variables instead of the user email or user ID as the variable name suggests.

```
 match /users/{userEmail}
 match /products/{userId}
```

You may of course create the Document IDs to have email addresses rather than auto generated sequences in which case above match conditions might work as expected.

**b)** The usage of `request.auth.uid.userEmail` is incorrect. The correct way to refer to email from a user's request authentication state is `"request.auth.token.email"`. You can read about the `request.auth & resource variable references` on Firestore public docs -[documentation1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth) & [documentation2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource) to use correct syntax.

**c)** Below are some corrections made to the security rules. This should work.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userDocId} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /products/{productDocId}{
        allow read, write: if request.auth.token.email == resource.data.userId
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct syntax is

```
        allow read, write: if request.auth.token.email == userId
```

Please refer to the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth#identify_users) for more details.