# After changing security rules in firestore, db transaction cannot be done

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My current security rule in my flutter - firestore application is as follows and it works fine.

```
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
 match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if true;
  }
 }
}
```

However, after changing the rule to below, all db transaction does not work. It throws the following error when retrieving data.

```
Listen for Query(target=Query(uses/CKZkpfewcElSqa4Dsgo9sMq3Ziit1/post order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

 service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
      }
     }
    }
```

Then I reverted back to the previous rule which was working, but I am wondering why app still throws the same error. Can anybody tell what is wrong in the rule?

Comment: So it seems that the user is not signed in to Firebase Authentication when they try to access the database, which is why the rules then reject them. If you think that is an error, edit your question to **also** show the [minimal, complete/standalone **code** that any of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Frank Thanks. Then why it is still not working after reverting back to the previous rule. It just checks 'allow read, write: if true; '

Comment: Does this answer your question? [allow read, write: if request.auth != null;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69648609/allow-read-write-if-request-auth-null)